# Decent number program terminated

Tags: java, list, for-loop

Actually I wrote a program for to find the decent number..

A Decent Number has the following properties:

3, 5, or both as its digits. No other digit is allowed.
Number of times 3 appears is divisible by 5.
Number of times 5 appears is divisible by 3.

Input Format:
The 1st line will contain an integer T, the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer N. i.e. the number of digits in the number.

Output Format:
Largest Decent Number having N digits. If no such number exists, tell Sherlock that he is wrong and print −1.

Constraints
1≤T≤20,
1≤N≤100000

```
public class TrySamp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = scan.nextInt();
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            list.add(scan.nextLong());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            long s = list.get(i);

            long c = 5 * ((2 * s) % 3);
            System.out.println(c);
            if (c > s) {
                System.out.print(-1); 
            } else {
                int o=1;
                System.out.println("=="+ (o <= (s - c)));
                for (int j = 1; j <= (s - c); j++) {
                    System.out.print(5);
                }
                for (int k = 1; k <= c; k++) {
                    System.out.print(3);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("lo");
        }
    }
}
```

The program works fine for the sample input

Sample Input:

> 4 1 3 5 11

Sample Output

> -1 555 33333 55555533333

but the program terminates when I give the input as

> 1 100000

or

> 1 10000

can anyone suggest me a method to solve this problem??..

Comment: You can't work with numbers having 10000 (or even 100) digits using `long`s. You'll have to use BigInteger. The max value of `long` has 20 digits.

Comment: @eran Actually i am not storing the value i just want to print the values.
when i print it in the for loop it  gets terminated

Comment: I'd also recommend splitting each of your constraints into a method for better readability and reuseability, as the current implementation is quite static

Comment: Is it a secret or why don't you tell us about the exception/error you're getting?

Comment: @Tom I am not getting any exceptions  the only problem is the program gets terminated when i give the input as 1  10000

Comment: @vineethPrabhakaran A Java program doesn't just terminate. And since you have no empty `catch` block, you're just missing it somehow. How do you run your program?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me for both input values `1 100000` and `1 10000`. Am using openjdk-7 on ubuntu 14 (x64).

Comment: if you can't store such large numbers, how can you print it? integer overflow in Java won't give you an exception

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem, Eclipse does not allows you to print such large numbers on your console.

If you try to run the program in console it will work as expected.

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n = scan.nextInt();
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        list.add(scan.nextLong());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        long s = list.get(i);
        long c = 5 * ((2 * s) % 3);
        if (c > s) {
            System.out.print(-1);
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            int o = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= (s - c); j++) {
                System.out.print(5);
            }
            for (int k = 1; k <= c; k++) {
                System.out.print(3);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will be able to post code if it comes with an explanation of what it does, to help others. Code on its own is never as helpful as code with some accompanying text to say why things were done, etc.